# How do I track session of user in Unity3d?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, unity-game-engine, request

If a user is inactive, then the user would be logged out due to session time out, but how do I track session or activity of a user in Unity3D?

That is, if a user is active in Unity web player by clicking on the objects or doing some kind of action, then the session should be kept active and the user should not be logged out. If the user is inactive and nothing happens in the web player, then the user should be logged out.

I'm not asking how to implement session time out... I'm asking how to track user activity in unit web player in ASP .NET MVC web app, so as to keep unity web player active when necessary.

Hope this makes sense. Like what kind of request should be sent from server to unity to know if unity is active or not.

There's this:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html?

I know how to set it up but I'm not sure what kind of requests should I be firing or checking for...

Answer (score 0):

It seems your game requires clicking. You can simply take the time from one click to another via `OnMouseDown()` and check if it is greater than a time. You could also check last mouse position with current mouse position.

The best way is you make a set of all the possible keys that can be used. Then make a smaller subset that represents the whole set and test for use on those.